# Как игнорировать перевод строк и пробелов при вводе?

Tags: java

Как игнорировать перевод строк и пробелов при вводе? Входной поток содержит набор целых чисел, отделённых друг от друга произвольным количеством пробелов и переводов строк. Необходимо занести эти числа в список. При вводе считываются числа только до перевода строки.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String numbers = reader.readLine();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(numbers);

ArrayList<Double> num = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNext()){
    if(scanner.hasNext()) num.add(scanner.nextDouble());
    else scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: А что Вы подразумеваете под `игнорировать перевод строк и пробелов при вводе`?

Comment: И в чем проблема? И Ваш код бы не помешал.

Comment: В данном примере метод ```readLine``` работает именно так (данные прекращают считываться при перевед строки).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Вариант решения*

Можно считывать данные стоки ввода в цикле:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            String numbers;
            Scanner scanner;
            List<Double> num;

            while(null != (numbers = reader.readLine())){
                scanner = new Scanner(numbers);
                num = new ArrayList<Double>();
                while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                    num.add(scanner.nextDouble());

                }   
            }
            //TODO: process num
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```